# How do I send Excel data (multiple individual ranges) seperated by carriage returns to an Outlook mail body

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to send certain sections of an excel file into an Outlook mail body.

I need the formatting of the data, as I am working with data inside tables and with different cell fill colours and font colours, so it can't be stored in a string AFAIK.

I need carriage returns to separate the tables being pasted into outlook so that other text can be manually added to the email body in between the tables without distorting the table formatting.

The code below, shows what needs to be done but wont work as it returns a runtime error 13, type mismatch on the ".HTMLBody" line. I've spend a long time trying different ways to do this, but this is the way I need it to work I just don't know which data types to use and how to properly do it.

Keep in mind that in both examples of my code below I have cut out most of the data range pasting because it would be redundant code.

```
Sub sendToOutlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Dim bodyFieldA As Range
    Dim bodyFieldB As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = Range("L18").Value
        .CC = Range("L19").Value
        .BCC = Range("L20").Value
        .Subject = Range("L1") & " " & Range("N1").Text _
                   & " " & Range("O1") & " " & Range("R1").Text _
                   & " " & Range("S1")

        Set bodyFieldA = Range("A26:I33")
        Set bodyFieldB = Range("A34:I34")

        .HTMLBody = bodyFieldA + vbCrLf + bodyFieldB + "<HTML><body><body></HTML>"
        .display
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

My old version only works if Outlook has already been given focus by the user once, otherwise the "sendkeys" which I use instead of carriage returns are sent to excel instead, ruining the worksheet data.

Also, if the ".TO" field is left blank the "sendkeys" are sent there instead of the email body.

I need to fix this problem, so the above code is my attempt at a solution for it, while the code below is my old code that does the job but with a lot of Band-Aid work and problems less experienced users who will be using the macro will not be able to deal with.

```
Sub sendToOutlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim olInsp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim oRng As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = Range("L18").Value
        .CC = Range("L19").Value
        .BCC = Range("L20").Value
        .Subject = _
            Range("L1") & " " & Range("N1").Text _
            & " " & Range("O1") & " " & Range("R1").Text _
            & " " & Range("S1")

        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range

        'force html format
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><body><body></HTML>"
        .display

        oRng.collapse 1
        Range("A26:I33").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste
        SendKeys "{ENTER}", True

        oRng.collapse 1
        Range("A34:I34").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste
        SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
    End With

    'deselect cell range
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using: "oRng = ORng & chr(13)" ...However, the chr(13) stays inside the tables, which ruins their size formatting, and doesn't split the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the second set of code above, which copy-pastes the tables into the Word-based email body, I came up with the following code. Basically, we're "priming" the document with a couple of CrLf's before pasting the tables.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sendToOutlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim olInsp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim oRng As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = Range("L18").Value
        .CC = Range("L19").Value
        .BCC = Range("L20").Value
        .Subject = _
            Range("L1") & " " & Range("N1").Text _
            & " " & Range("O1") & " " & Range("R1").Text _
            & " " & Range("S1")

        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range

        'force html format
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><body><body></HTML>"
        .display

        '--- start with two CrLf's, so we can add the first table
        '    in between them...
        oRng.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf

        '--- now reselect the entire document, collapse our cursor to the end
        '    and back up one character (so that the table inserts before the CrLf)
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 0
        oRng.Move 1, -1
        Range("A26:I33").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste

        '--- finally move the cursor all the way to the end and paste the
        '    second table
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 0
        Range("A34:I34").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste
        'SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
    End With

    'deselect cell range
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: My font types and sizes aren't kept. Also the table cells are wider and taller (padding?)  than what they are set to in Excel. However this is definitely closer, thank you!

Comment: Also, my methods before were keeping all the formatting as I needed, the only problem I have is the carriage returns splitting the tables. This is a lot of code to work around just to separate tables with an empty line. Is there an easier way to just add the carriage returns?

Comment: I reworked the above code to use your copy-paste solution. Based on your second set of code. See if that works better for you, or at least gives you an example to work from.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to modify your code to do exactly what I needed. The problem that I was getting while leaving the TO field blank, as well as the "sendkeys" issue are both resolved, I have posted an answer to this question with the code I used to satisfy any curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

The code below solves both of my issues. Thanks to PeterT who gave me a strategy to use.

```
Sub sendToOutlook()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim olInsp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim oRng As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = Range("L18").Value
        .CC = Range("L19").Value
        .BCC = Range("L20").Value
        .Subject = _
            Range("L1") & " " & Range("N1").Text _
            & " " & Range("O1") & " " & Range("R1").Text _
            & " " & Range("S1")

        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range

        'force html format
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><body><body></HTML>"
        .display

        '--- start with 6 CrLf's, so we can place each table
        '    above all but the last used...
        oRng.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

        '--- now reselect the entire document, collapse our cursor to the end
        '    and back up six characters (so that the table inserts before the FIRST CrLf)
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 0
        oRng.Move 1, -6
        Range("A1:I8").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste

        '--- now reselect the entire document, collapse our cursor to the end
        '    and back up five characters (so that the table inserts before the SECOND CrLf)
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 0
        oRng.Move 1, -5
        Range("A9:I9").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste

        '--- now reselect the entire document, collapse our cursor to the end
        '    and back up four characters (so that the table inserts before the THIRD CrLf)
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 0
        oRng.Move 1, -4
        Range("A11:I22").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste

        '--- now reselect the entire document, collapse our cursor to the end
        '    and back up three characters (so that the table inserts before the FOURTH CrLf)
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 0
        oRng.Move 1, -3
        Range("A24:I24").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste

        '--- now reselect the entire document, collapse our cursor to the end
        '    and back up two characters (so that the table inserts before the FIFTH CrLf)
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 0
        oRng.Move 1, -2
        Range("A26:I33").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste

        '--- now reselect the entire document, collapse our cursor to the end
        '    and back up one character (so that the table inserts before the SIXTH CrLf)
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 0
        oRng.Move 1, -1
        Range("A34:I34").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste


        '--- finally move the cursor all the way to the end and paste the
        '    second table BELOW the SIXTH CrLf
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 0
        Range("A36:I47").Select
        Selection.Copy
        oRng.Paste
    End With

    'deselect cell range
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing

End Sub
```